# Threejs how to attach an image plane in surface of a sphere using hdr texture?

Tags: javascript, three.js, hdr

I use threejs to create a sphere with HDR texture. Now i want to attach/place a 2D image on the surface of this sphere (on HDR texture) as below:

[image]

As you see, this image is float in the sphere, not on surface.

Well, my question here: how can i attach an 2d image plane in surface of a sphere ?

Thank for your reading